# NodeJS test continuing async flow with Jasmine 2.4

Tags: node.js, testing, jasmine, async-await

My route calls a function `startJob()` that immediately returns a response "Job started."  It also calls a function `runJob()`, which continues with the job flow (async).

Obviously, I can't just do `const jobResults = await startJob()`, since that function just returns "Job started."  The actual results of the job are not available until all the subsequent functions complete.

So I need a way to check the results of the test after all the functions complete, meaning I need to know when all the functions complete.

The last function in the flow `logResults()` is not going to work to spy on, because I need it to call through (including an async call).  Jasmine doesn't allow me to call it through and then call another function that checks the results.

My idea was to add a function at the end of `logResults()` called `finishJob` and spy on that. `finishJob()` wouldn't do anything, so I wouldn't need to call it through.
Pseudo-code: 
`spyOn(finishJob).and.callFake( [function that checks the results] )`

However, it seems like bad practice to add a function to the code purely for testing reasons.

Other possible solutions would be using some kind of node watchers, a state change machine, or just doing a timeout (also bad practice?  but quick implementation...)

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking: which of the proposed solutions is best?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I'm happy with.  I decided to start the testing at a different point in the flow.

Instead calling `await startJob()` to start the test, I called `await runJob()`, which kicks off the asynchronous process and gets the results.

That way, I could know when the process finishes (using `await` keyword obvs) and check the results at that time.